# Channel Entries API and entry to a Category

Tags: channel, entries, channel-entries-api

Is it possible to add entries into categories when creating them with the Channel Entries API cant see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Within the channel entry API, you can pass the data array containing the array of category ids like:

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

$data = array(
    'title'         => 'ENTRY TITLE',
    'entry_date'    => time(),
    'channel_id'    => x,
    'category'      => array($category_id)
);

ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);

ee()->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry($channel_id, $data);
```